# How is the "target" of the love potion effect set?

Tags: harry-potter

When someone drinks a "love" potion then he/she becomes obsessed with someone for a short time. But how is this someone choosen?

It is not (always) the one who crafted the potion because Fred and George were selling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I come to the same conclusion as @Himarm, but by a different route:

The love potions have to go through some ridiculous contortions, to get the recipient to take them, **from the giver**:

> "I'm not talking about your stupid so-called prince," said Hermione ,
>   giving his book a nasty look as though it had been rude to her. "I'm talki ng
>   about earlier. I went into the girl's bathroom just before I came in here and
>   there were about a dozen girls in there, including that Romilda Vane , **trying
>   to decide how to slip you a love potion**. They're all hoping they're going to
>   get you to take them to Slughorn's party, **and thay all seem to have bought
>   Fred and George's love potions**, which I'm afraid to say probably work --"
>   *Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 15: The Unbreakable Vow*

- Now, here's the two important things:

  1. It takes a hard effort for someone to get their target to drink their potion. Romilda tried to offer Harry Gillywater. Then chocolates. etc...

     **The girls held a strategy session on how to slip Harry a love potion, in the quote above**.
  2. Fred and George are (1) Devious and (2) Love to sell their services for money.
- Ergo, if it was possible to set up a love potion without spiking it via your own hair or such, ala Polyjuice, **Fred and George would have offered an extra-pay service**, pronto, of delivering the potion to the target - they clearly would be far more successful at it than random people plotting in the bathroom.
- Ergo, since the girls still had to strategize, that service wasn't offered by Weasleys.
- Ergo, you need the potion giver to do something personal with the potion before giving it.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK cannon never gives us a love potion recipe, but from other recipes I think we can say that the person with whom the victim is intended to love, must place a their own hair, or clipping into the potion before it is "active".

the poly juice potion requires the targets hair or clipping so it knows what to transform you into,

> “This is the most complicated potion I’ve ever seen,” said 
>   Hermione as they scanned the recipe. “Lacewing flies, leeches, 
>   fluxweed, and knotgrass,” she murmured, running her finger down 
>   the list of ingredients. “Well, they’re easy enough, they’re in the 
>   student store-cupboard, we can help ourselves. . . . Oooh, look, 
>   powdered horn of a bicorn — don’t know where we’re going to get 
>   that — shredded skin of a boomslang — that’ll be tricky, too — 
>   **and of course a bit of whoever we want to change into.”**
>
> “Now what?” Ron whispered.  “**We separate it into three glasses and add
>   the hairs.”**